# Spark + cassandra - Just one record getting inserted

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, hive

Am trying to get data from hive and insert the same in Cassandra using Spark.Very surprisingly i see only one record inserted into cassandra inspite of Data frame having 4000+ records.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import java.math.BigDecimal

case class sales(wk_nbr: Int,
                    store_nbr: Int,
                    sales_amt: BigDecimal)


object HiveConnector extends App {

  val cassandraConfig = ConfigFactory.load("cassandra.conf")

  println("cassandraConfig loaded = " + cassandraConfig)

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("HiveConnector")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:/data/raw/historical/tables")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    .config("mapred.input.dir.recursive","true")
    .config("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "***********")
    .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "*****un****")
    .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "******pw*****")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .master("yarn").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val query = "select wk_nbr,store_nbr,sum(sales_amt) as sales_amt from scan where visit_dt between '2018-05-08' and '2018-05-11' group by wm_yr_wk_nbr,store_nbr"

  val resDF = spark.sql(query)

  resDF.persist()

  println("RESDF size = " + resDF.count()) //prints the record count

  println("RESDF sample rec = " + resDF.show(2)) //see 2 records in the log

  CassandraConnector(spark.sparkContext).withSessionDo { spark =>
    spark.execute("CREATE TABLE raaspoc.sales_data (wk_nbr INT PRIMARY KEY, store_nbr INT, sales_amt DOUBLE)")
  }


/*
  None of the following saveToCassandra work - meaning not inserting all records but only one record

*/


  resDF.map { x => sales.apply(x.get(0).asInstanceOf[Int], x.get(1).asInstanceOf[Int],x.get(2).asInstanceOf[BigDecimal])
  }.rdd.saveToCassandra("raaspoc","sales_data")   // Not working

  resDF.rdd.saveToCassandra("raaspoc","sales_data")  // Not working

  resDF.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("table" -> "sales_data", "keyspace" -> "raaspoc")).save() // Not working

  resDF.write.cassandraFormat("sales_data","raaspoc").save() // Not working


/*
  When the data frame is written to HDFS, i see all 4000+ records in the sales.csv

*/

  resDF.write.format("csv").save("hdfs:/dev/test/sales.csv")

  println("RESDF size after write to cassandra = " + resDF.count()) //prints 4732 (record count)

  spark.close()


}
```

I dont see any errors in the log and Spark submit completes without any errors but inserts only one record. Following is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.raas</groupId>
  <artifactId>RaasDataPipelines</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.0</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.2.0</spark.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.11</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>
                shade
              </goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>

        <configuration>
          <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>

          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.google</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>shaded.guava</shadedPattern>
              <includes>
                <include>com.google.**</include>
              </includes>

              <excludes>
                <exclude>com.google.common.base.Optional</exclude>
                <exclude>com.google.common.base.Absent</exclude>
                <exclude>com.google.common.base.Present</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>

          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>




  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

is there a possibility that your primary key(wk_nbr) to be the same on all the 4000+ rows?

Comment: This is the case about 99% of the time someone reports this.